# Show that $\mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_p$ is not generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Show that group $A = \mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_p$  is not generated by two elements. ($p$ is prime.)

any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: The group $A$ is not isomorphic to $G=Z_{p^2} \times Z_p$, since $G$ has elements of order $p^2$, but $A$ doesn't.

Comment: Hint: let $a,b$ be any two elements. They have order at most $p$. How large can the subgroup generated by them be?

Comment: BTW, can you prove $\mathbb{R}^3$ has no spanning set of size two? (As a real vector space, not as an additive group.)

Comment: deleted the mistake . thanks

Comment: Note: the fact that two elements of order $p$ cannot generate a group of order greater than $p^2$ depends on the fact that the group is abelian, which is obvious from the structure, but is not explicit in the proofs (which also work within abelian contexts). To see this note that the symmetric group on three elements of order $6$ is generated by any pair of elements of order $2$ and the alternating group on four elements of order $12$ can be generated by a pair of elements of order $3$. This comment is to highlight that abelian methods may fail in non-abelian contexts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're wrong for the isomorphisms.

**Hint:**

$\mathbb Z_p\oplus\mathbb Z_p\oplus\mathbb Z_p$ is a $\mathbb Z_p$-vector space. What is its dimension?

Comment: This feels more like a rewording of the problem than a solution...

Comment: 3 dimensions . so can I say that (1,0,0) , (0,1,0) , (0,0,1) will always be in the groups and I can't make them from any two elements because ill always have one of the three elements to be 1 or 0 not both?

Comment: I didn't intend to give a solution, but a hint. The problem comes down to a problem of *vectors spaces*, not groups. This observation gives new tools to solve the problem.

Comment: @gpgpgp: More  simply if $2$ elements generate the group, they generate it as a vector space, hence the dimension would be at most $2$.

Comment: that it has 2 dimensions. got it thanks

Comment: I understand your intent. My point is that this approach leverages the non-trivial fact that all bases of a vector space have the same cardinality. So if *any* given pair of linearly independent vectors don't span a space, then none will. My issue with this is that it doesn't generalise to other examples as nicely: maybe because they aren't vector spaces (but still free modules), or maybe because finding an explicit pair of linearly independent elements and proving that they don't span the whole space requires a non-negligible amount of work.

Comment: The invariant basis number is non-trivial but it remains a basic fact about finite dimensional vector spaces. One cannot always reinvent the wheel. That said, the combinatorial argument  is a fine argument.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think it's reinventing the wheel in this case, as for a course at this level prior knowledge of linear algebra is not always assumed.

Answer (score 7):

This hint is in the comments, but let's say $x,y$ are two elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p$. The subgroup generated by them is given by all elements of the form
$$ax+by$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ (written multiplicatively this is more obvious as it becomes $x^ay^b$). There are $p$ distinct possibilities for $a$ and $p$ distinct possibilities for $b$ (since $x$ and $y$ have order $p$). How many elements does this generate? If it's less than $p^3$ then two elements cannot generate the whole group.